# Property not found on type org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, seam

I am trying to create a  with a list to choose from. 
I am using JBoss 5.1 and Seam 2.2.
My list should be dynamically populated from my DB, but for the moment I am trying to create a simple list. Which is not working!!

My html:

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{browseQuarters.qList}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The bean has a "qList" member:

```
@In(required=false) 
    private List<SelectItem> qList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
```

Which has getters and setters:

```
public List<SelectItem> getqList(){
        qList.add(new SelectItem(1,"one"));

        return qList;
}

public void setqList(List<SelectItem> qList) {
        this.qList = qList;
}
```

However, when I try running the page, I get this exception: 
Property not found on type org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_2

My project is generated using Jboss Tools, and I saw the other pages generated from the DB (to generate the entities) have a page.xml with the parameters defined..When creating this new form with New -> Seam form I only got a xhtml page and corresponding bean.

What's going wrong? I am of course a Seam/Java EE newbie, but have to do this ASAP :(

Answer (score 1):

I think Seam/JSF will look for a method called getQList rather than the method you have, getqList. Try changing the names of the getter & setter.

Tip: Eclipse can generate compliant getters & setters for you.

Comment: I found the problem, added the new methods to the interface but did not deploy it so there was an inconsistency there.

Comment: Hey, I come across the same question. seems that my change not deploy after Jboss restart. How you solve it?

Comment: Jboss is always not getting my code change in JSP files.